# Merge conflicts in a pull request

Tags: code-organization

A coworker and me had an interesting discussion about Code reviews. One said, merge conflicts will be resolved after an approvement the other said merge conflicts have to be resolved in order to get an approvement, so the Branch is ready for merging.

Which workflow works better in the real world?

Comment: They are all better ... so any definition of "better".

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** merge conflicts have to be resolved in order to get an approvement

First of all: if you ok with code A, will you be with code A+B? (where A and B - some set of commits).

In the other words: if you accepted code review, then you should automatically reject your approval after next code change.

Therefore each code change (or additional commits) should reject approvals.

Next: 
You could not merge code without conflicts resolving. Therefore you will need change your code before merging (e.g. you have to push new version). This action will reject all approvals, so: **you have to fix merge conflicts before approvals will be set**